# any+time picker does not close when click outside the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Any+Time picker. The popup is display when I click on a date, when I double click on the popup or click the cross the popup is closed. 
What I want now is to close this popup if the user click outside.

Thanks for your help.

I included the JS file: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/AnyTime/anytime,js

then in my main page I am using the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dp").AnyTime_picker({
        format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i" 
    });
});
```

If an input text uses the class 'dp' the picker is displayed.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code?

Comment: if you scroll down to the first example at: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/  The date picker opens up just fine when clicking on the date picker field..  Then if I click outside of the date picker area it closes just fine.. It's the default functionality.    Or maybe I don't  understand your question.